# Can firefox-web be programmed to listen to all notifications from the opened tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to listen to all notification from all the opened tabs and say display all together till the user deletes it?

I did check the documentation and found only these events for notifications

```
Events

onButtonClicked
onClicked
onClose
```

And I also read about using a service worker to listen to push-notifications. But I'm looking for all notifications. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to listen to all notifications from web pages (content), or are you also trying to listen for notifications from other extensions?

Comment: web pages, notifications like Whatsapp msgs or fb msgs

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes. You will need to use a content script to redefine `Notification` within the page context such that instead of actually calling the `Notification` API, it informs your extension that the page script has attempted to create a `Notification`.